# Black screen in Cordova Windows 10 UWP app with ExtJS 6.5.2

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, extjs, uwp

I have exactly the same problem as Daniel Twigg in his subject ([Black screen in Cordova Windows 10 UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475683/black-screen-in-cordova-windows-10-uwp-app/50368018?noredirect=1#comment87752171_50368018)).
I invite you to read it because it describes EXTREMELY well his problem, which by extension is also mine.

In his subject, he explains having a discussion with a sencha member who helped him solve his problem.

Nevertheless, they did not give the solution and after trying to comment on his topic I got a return from the site that asks me to post my own topic and so here I am:)

Thank you for your help. Kind regards.